# Binary file read pre-defined number of Byte/ Bytes using C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, binaryfiles

**Scenario**
I have a Binary file which is a output from a certain system. The vendor has provided us with the description of the file encoding. Its very complicated because the encoding follows a certain methodology. For eg. the first Byte is ISO coded, we need to decode it first, if the value matches the provided list then it has some meaning. Then the next 15 Bytes also ISO encoded, we need to decode it and compare. Similarly after certain position, few Bytes are Binary encoded.. so on and so forth.

**Action so far**
I will be using C# WinForm Application. So far I have looked at various documents and all point to FileStream/ BinaryReader combination, since my file size are in the range of 1G to 1.8G. I cannot put the whole file in a Byte[] either.

**Problem**
I am facing issue in reading the file Byte by Byte. According to the above scenario, first I need to read only 1 Byte then 15 Bytes then 10 Bytes and so on and so forth. How to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Both Stream and BinaryReader have methods for reading a single byte and reading multiple bytes (Stream: ReadByte/Read, BinaryReader: ReadByte/ReadBytes) - neither of them require you to read the whole file into a byte[].

Answer (score 1):

**BinaryReader is the way to go, as it uses a stream the memory usage will be low.**

Now you can do something like below :

```
internal struct MyHeader
{
    public byte FirstByte;
    // etc
}

internal class MyFormat
{
    private readonly string _fileName;

    private MyFormat(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }


    public MyHeader Header { get; private set; }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
    }


    public static MyFormat FromFileName(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

        // read the header of your file
        var header = new MyHeader();
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
        {
            byte b1 = reader.ReadByte();
            if (b1 != 0xAA)
            {
                // return null or throw an exception
            }
            header.FirstByte = b1;

            // you can also read block of bytes with a BinaryReader
            var readBytes = reader.ReadBytes(10);

            // etc ... whenever something's wrong return null or throw an exception
        }

        // when you're done reading your header create and return the object
        var myFormat = new MyFormat(fileName);
        myFormat.Header = header;

        // the rest of the object is delivered only when needed, see method below

        return myFormat;
    }

    public object GetBigContent()
    {
        var content = new object();
        // use FileName and Header property to get your big content and return it
        // again, use a BinaryReader with 'using' statement here
        return content;
    }
}
```

### Explanations

Call `MyFormat.FromFileName` to create one of these object, inside it :

- you parse the header, whenever an error occurs return null or throw an exception
- once your header is parsed you create the object and return it **and that's it**

**Since you just read the header, provide a way for reading the bigger parts in the file.**

Pseudo-example:

Use `GetBigContent` or whatever you want to call it whenever you need to read a large part of it.

Using `Header` and `FileName` inside that method you will have everything you need to return a content from this file *on-demand*.

By using this approach,

- you quickly return a valid object by only parsing its header
- you do not consume 1.8Gb at first call
- you return only what the user needs, *on-demand*

For your encoding-related stuff the `Encoding` class will probably be helpful to you :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Answer (score -1):

> BinaryReader.ReadBytes Method
>   Reads the specified number of bytes from the current stream into a byte array and advances the current position by that number of bytes.

```
public virtual byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP probably knows that, he's looking for a general approach on how to tackle the problem.

Comment: "I need to read only 1 Byte then 15 Bytes then 10 Bytes and so on and so forth. How to accomplish this."  I thought if anything my answer was too long.

Comment: And he cannot put the whole 1.8Gb file in an array either.